# Problem with Instagram api since July 2022

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

After ?__a=1 no longer worked and gave an error, I read in one of the topics that I should use ?__a=1&__d=dis instead, but the problem I have is that I don't know how to use it in the php code. Because in any case, I come across the Instagram login page
*i want use it on host
thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you want to do with this API??